# "After completion" vs "after the completion"

Tags: articles

Should I use definite article in the following sentence?

> After (the) completion of this task, we should go to sleep.

Comment: Both are fine. As [this NGram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=after+the+completion+of+this%2Cafter+completion+of+this&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) shows, until 40-50 years ago it was far more common to include the article, but increasingly today (especially in AmE as opposed to BrE) we don't include it. But the new kid on the block today is ***after completing this** [task]*, which has become more common than both the others put together.

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna look at this from an eighth-grade perspective (my current pov), I have to note though, this is just how my teacher would do it and I'm from California so things may be different where other people live and it varies per school.

> After completion of the task, we should go to sleep.

My teacher would tell me that I should put the word "the" in-between or that I forgot to do so, I would not be marked down, but I would have gotten the heads up for the future. Meaning that it is ok, just not something that is considered the most common in speech.

> After the completion of the task, we should go to sleep.

This would be considered more acceptable and I would be okay grade-wise and no additional comments adressing it. it is kind of proper which is not bad at all, but a lot of people (the fellow Californians that I have met at least) would not say it like that in a normal conversation, I do not know about work situations. However, I would say this in conversation but that is just how I talk.

Thw way below is more common and less-proper.

> After completeing the/this task, we should go to sleep.

You will probably hear this more than the other two. You could put the or this in that spot hence why I put both but I feel like you would hear "this" more than "the" in this case.